# How do I use a for loop to make multiple similar arrays based on user input?

Tags: arrays, c

I want to create multiple arrays for player decks in a card game. Each deck will be called playerCards[player number]. Ex: playerCards1, playerCards2, and so on depending on how many players the user inputs.

My plan was to create a for loop that would declare the arrays, but it doesn't work. Is there another way to do this properly?

Here is the code. playerNum is based on input from the user. I should be the number at the end of the variable (Ex: playerCards1) and 10 is the number of integers in each array

```
for(int i = 0; i < playerNum; i++){
    int playerCards[i][10];
}
```

Comment: There's not enough here to answer your question. You need to post a [complete problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): enough to see the input, the actual output, and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop. You can use variable-length arrays in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numberOfPlayers = 4;
    int playerCards[numberOfPlayers][10];
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            playerCards[i][j] = j + 10 * i + 1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
            printf("Player %d, Card %d: %d\n", i + 1, j + 1, playerCards[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Player 1, Card 1: 1
Player 1, Card 2: 2
Player 1, Card 3: 3
Player 1, Card 4: 4
Player 1, Card 5: 5
Player 1, Card 6: 6
Player 1, Card 7: 7
Player 1, Card 8: 8
Player 1, Card 9: 9
Player 1, Card 10: 10
Player 2, Card 1: 11
Player 2, Card 2: 12
Player 2, Card 3: 13
Player 2, Card 4: 14
Player 2, Card 5: 15
Player 2, Card 6: 16
Player 2, Card 7: 17
Player 2, Card 8: 18
Player 2, Card 9: 19
Player 2, Card 10: 20
Player 3, Card 1: 21
Player 3, Card 2: 22
Player 3, Card 3: 23
Player 3, Card 4: 24
Player 3, Card 5: 25
Player 3, Card 6: 26
Player 3, Card 7: 27
Player 3, Card 8: 28
Player 3, Card 9: 29
Player 3, Card 10: 30
Player 4, Card 1: 31
Player 4, Card 2: 32
Player 4, Card 3: 33
Player 4, Card 4: 34
Player 4, Card 5: 35
Player 4, Card 6: 36
Player 4, Card 7: 37
Player 4, Card 8: 38
Player 4, Card 9: 39
Player 4, Card 10: 40
```

Comment: But I want to make more than one array depending on how many players there are. Wouldn't this just make one array called playerCards4? Thanks

Comment: @furiosa No, that makes an array of 4 arrays of 10 ints. Player 1 is `playerCards[0]`, player 2 is `playerCards[1]` and so on. Card 1 of player 1 is `playerCards[0][0]`, card 1 or player 2 is `playerCards[1][0]`, ...

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense